# Javascript - Help cut title

Tags: javascript

Thor 2 - THE DARK WORLD [HD] <<< **I want to use the code to cut them into 3 parts:**

1. Thor 2
2. THE DARK WORLD
3. HD

**My old code was only divided into two parts**

1.hor 2 - THE DARK WORLD
  2.HD

```
 var Enumber = new Array();      
    $(".data h2").each(function(i){
      var text = $(this).text();
      if(text.indexOf('[') != -1 || text.indexOf(']') != -1){
        var Ntext      = text.split('[')[0];
        Enumber[i] = text.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];
        $(this).text(Ntext);
      }
    });
    $("span.time").each(function(i){          
      $(this).fadeIn("slow");
      if(Enumber[i] != undefined){
        $(this).text(Enumber[i]);
      }else{
        $(this).text('HD');
      }

    });
```

Comment: What is your issue, exactly? Please edit the question and add more detail about where you are stuck and what isn't working as expected

Comment: Nice movie..but what is real issue? dont you like it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rjMh/3/)

```
<span class="title">Thor 2 - THE DARK WORLD [HD]</span>

var title = $('.title').text();

var firstPart = title.split('-');
var seccondPart = firstPart[1].split('[');
var thirdPart = seccondPart[1].slice(0,-1);


$('body').append('<br />1--> ' + firstPart[0]);
$('body').append('<br />2--> ' + seccondPart[0]);
$('body').append('<br />3--> ' + thirdPart);
```

Comment: I want a similar script on :(